# Setting up v3 of in-app billing

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app on the market.  My next version I want to implement an in-app purchase.  I have been following the (long) guide for [setup of v3 of in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html).  I completed the first 3 lessons from that link but now my code has a load of errors that all are on the same variable.

In the code below, `spreadsheet` is my PRODUCT_ID from my Developer Console for what is being purchased.  Every time the variable `spreadsheet` is used, the error is:  "Spreadsheet cannot be resolved to a variable."

```
    public class BibleStudy extends SwarmActivity {
        Context c;
        IabHelper mHelper;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.biblestudy);

            c = this;

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = a + b + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k;

        // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
    }

    // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own.
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            /*
             * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
             * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
             * verifyDeveloperPayload().
             */

            // Do we have the premium upgrade?
            Purchase spreadsheetPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(spreadsheet);

            updateUi();
        }
    };

    // User clicked the "Download Spreadsheet!" button.
    public void onBuyButtonClick(View v) {

        // launch the gas purchase UI flow.
        // We will be notified of completion via mPurchaseFinishedListener

        /* TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See the comments on 
         *        verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use 
         *        an empty string, but on a production app you should carefully generate this. */
        String payload = ""; 

        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, spreadsheet, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if(!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

        /*
         * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
         * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
         * 
         * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and 
         * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the 
         * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on 
         * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
         * random string you originally generated.
         *
         * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
         * 
         * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
         *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
         * 
         * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
         *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on 
         *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
         * 
         * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
         * installations is recommended.
         */

        return true;
    }

    // Callback for when a purchase is finished
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if(result.isFailure()) {
                complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            if(!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                return;
            }

            else if(purchase.getSku().equals(spreadsheet)) {
                // bought the premium upgrade!
                alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
//                mIsPremium = true;
                updateUi();
            }
        }
    };

    // updates UI to reflect model
    public void updateUi() {

        // MATT: update a TextView to show link after purchase is done.

//        // update the car color to reflect premium status or lack thereof
//        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.free_or_premium)).setImageResource(mIsPremium ? R.drawable.premium : R.drawable.free);
//
//        // "Upgrade" button is only visible if the user is not premium
//        findViewById(R.id.upgrade_button).setVisibility(mIsPremium ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
//
//        // "Get infinite gas" button is only visible if the user is not subscribed yet
//        findViewById(R.id.infinite_gas_button).setVisibility(mSubscribedToInfiniteGas ? 
//                View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
//
//        // update gas gauge to reflect tank status
//        if (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas) {
//            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gas_gauge)).setImageResource(R.drawable.gas_inf);
//        }
//        else {
//            int index = mTank >= TANK_RES_IDS.length ? TANK_RES_IDS.length - 1 : mTank;
//            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gas_gauge)).setImageResource(TANK_RES_IDS[index]);
//        }        
    }

    void complain(String message) {
        alert("Error: " + message);
    }

    void alert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setMessage(message);
        bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        bld.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

What I want to do when the purchase is successfully completed is provide the user with a link.  So I guess what I need is something that I can verify a purchase is complete with and then I can display a previously invisible TextView that provides them with the link.

My question is what have I done wrong from the tutorial and how can I get the errors to go away that appear on everyone the variable `spreadsheet` is used?

Comment: Maybe I am understanding you wrong, but protecting content you want people to purchase by putting it in an "invisible" String that could be extracted from the jar doesn't seem that safe to me

Comment: You understood correctly.  I am new to this and open for suggestions.  What would be the best route to handling that?

Comment: As I'm really not into the adroid development and the structure of In-App Purchases in their store I cannot provide you with a straight up working pattern, but I guess the Web can. However if your application does not have a server-client system of some kind you do not have to worry about such stuff too much, as one could always modify local stuff so it does what he wants it to do.

Comment: Updated my opening post.  Fixed most errors but one error is still there.  The one error appears many times throughout my code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had to declare the `spreadsheet` PRODUCT_ID.  I was thinking it was somehow pulling that from the server.

The code I integrated to fix problem:

```
static final String SKU_SPREADSHEET = "spreadsheet";
```